# How to get Values by Keys in Dictionary in For loop Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have got this code:

```
mylist = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
char = input('Enter char: ')
print(mylist[char])
```

and it works fine, but when I change it to this:

```
mylist = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
char = input('Enter char: ')
for char in mylist:
    if mylist[char] == char:
        print(mylist[char])
```

it dos not return any value, neither gives error message.

What is missing or wrong?

Thank you!

BR,
Valters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mylist = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
char = input('Enter char: ')

for char in mylist:
   if mylist[char] == char:
      print(mylist[char])
```

The problem with this is, when you are looping through a dictionary, you are checking if `key==value` which returns false and so nothing gets printed.

`for char in mylist` Here the char value is the keys so for your approach you have to modify the `if` condition. Instead of checking keys with value check keys with the entered chars.

So this will be like:

```
for key in mylist:
   if key == char:
      print(mylist[char])
```

And also instead of using loop and if condition, you can simply do as below:

```
if char in mylist:  # it checks if char is present in dict's key or not
   print(mylist[char])
```

Answer (score 3):

First, don't call 2 things the same here `char`. As you iterate the `dict` you get the `keys` and it's with these keys that you need to check for equality

```
mylist = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
char = input('Enter char: ')
for key in mylist:
    if key == char:
        print(mylist[key])
```

But doing that make the all purpose of using a `dict` disappear, you loose the performance of just doing `mylist[char]`

Comment: There is no need to use for loop. It actually does nothing in this case. Look at my solutions.

Comment: @wotesi if it is what you were looking for you can accept the answer ;)

Comment: @azro , in your case it will take O(n) time complexity. In my case it will be O(1) constant time note this.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I will need to use For loop as this is just part of the total code.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
char = input('Enter char: ')
if char in mylist.keys():
  print mylist.get(char, None)
```

> In your code you are actually trying to compare your key with dictionary value, and there it fails.

I hope I answered your problem.

Comment: Why checking the if, if you use .get() ?  Also None is already the default value, no need to provide it

Comment: mylist.keys() will return an list of keys at the end. And what if the user entered an input key which is not in dictionary say, ‘d’ then only go and print the value of that key from the dictionary. And I provided None as default value because if you tried to get a value of a key which is not present in that dictionary it should not fail

Comment: As I said None is already the default value in .get() you don't need to specify it

Comment: You are right! Thank you for advice. I will try this also as this is just part of my total code. I was doing wrong at the very beginning.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The char in the loop scoop is referring to a key of the mylist so when you are doing in the loop `if mylist[char] == char` it's checking if the key is equal to the value.
This is how it looks like inside the loop on each iteration.

```
mylist[char] 1 char a
mylist[char] 2 char b
mylist[char] 3 char c
```

so in the second example, it's not getting into the if statement that will create you a list of all lines that you can iterate over it over and over again.
You can do

```
mylist = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
char = input('Enter char: ')
if char in mylist:
    print(mylist[char])
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it wont work the reason is

mylist = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

char = input('Enter char: ') // <- here you are assigning the user input to the variable char.

for char in mylist: // <- the variable char is again assigned different value i.e the keys from the dictionary

if mylist[char] == char: // <- so here in first iteration the char will be "a" in " mylist[char] ", which is compared with char "a" , so the condition is as follows.

mylist["a"] == a // <- but here the value will be " 1 == a " since this condition fails

print(mylist[char]) // <- the  print statement is not executed.